# WCF and Akka.Net vs Pub/Sub

Tags: performance, wcf, akka, publish-subscribe, akka.net

We are using WCF for our company and we would like to make sure that we have complete separation between Client and Service.

We would like to study to see if using either Akka.Net (Orlean) or one of the Pub/Sub frameworks can help us to reduce the complexity and possibly improving our current system.

Which one would you choose ? Actor Model or PubSub and also why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's all about tradeoffs and the choice is depending on your priorities. To be honest I don't think that actor model or pub/sub will automagically help you to reduce complexity. If you're not familiar with patterns and philosophy of any of them it's probable, that the result will be quite opposite. While both are build on interesting concepts that may help you decouple components in your application, they move complexity to other places (such as transactions and read-write separation).

I've described a conceptual difference between actor model and pub/sub frameworks in other SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147003/akka-net-work-queues). But the general idea is: Pub/Sub are centered about message passing reliability, actor model is more about scaling out the application and it's resiliency.